# VBA excel issue with textbox

Tags: vba, excel

i have been tasked with creating a simpple sign in and out book for vistors but i am not sure on the corect code to use to get the time out to link with the correct name, 
what i would like if its possibe is when the vistors go to sign out the enter their name and the time get  added to their data from when they signed in.
 for example the vistors name is in column A row 2 i would like for the time to go to column G row 2 and so on for how many people sign in.

thanks

Comment: I believe the function you are looking for is called either time or now depending on the scope of the information you want to record.

Comment: Sounds like you also want a form (though perhaps that is where your textbox resides) - possibly the inbuilt functionality if 2016.

Comment: thanks for the quick help, i have 2 forms one where they input there name time in and other infomation which i have done, the other form is for them to sign out with what i would like is if the name  entered in to the text box matches one in coloumn A then the date to go in coloumn G - hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will insert the current date time into Column G based on the last used row for that column:

```
Sub InsertTime()

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Now()

End Sub
```

Edit:

To do this on the command of a button press you could do this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Name As String
Dim lRow As Long

Name = TextBox1.Value
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Now()
Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Name

'Reset TextBox For Next Entry
TextBox1.Value = ""

End Sub
```

You will just need a TextBox and a command button on the form:

[image]

Comment: hi thanks  for this the date is now being added, is there a way to link this code up so when a name is typed in to a text box matches a name in coloumn A it adds this to coloumn G thanks